# If checkbox is checked, change only style of that item

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm making a checkbox list and when someone checks a checkbox, I need it to change text from pending to done and also change the background to green. I've managed to make all that work with jQuery.

Except it styles every checkbox container and not just the one checked. How can I fix that? And how can I make it change back to its original style if someone unchecks the checkbox again after?

This is my code so far:

```js
$('.custom-control-input').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.pending').css('display', 'none')
        $('.done').css('display', 'block')
        $('.list-group-item').css('background-color','#4CAF50')
    }
})
```

```css
.done {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
</div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
  </div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
  </div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
</div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `$(this).closest('.list-group-item')` to change background of the only the parent of the checkedcheckbox

```js
$('.custom-control-input').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.pending').css('display', (this.checked)?'none':'block')
        $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.done').css('display', (this.checked)?'block':'none')
        $(this).closest('.list-group-item').css('background-color',(this.checked)?'#4CAF50':'')
})
```

```css
.done {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
</div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
  </div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
  </div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
</div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome that works! But it still doesn't change back to its original styling after I uncheck it again. Can that be done?

Comment: yes.. check that..  i have updated the answer/ also corrected the text change issue

Answer (score 0):

This script will fix

```js
$('.custom-control-input').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.list-group-item').css('background-color', '#fdb515');
    $(this).parents('.list-group-item').find('.mb-0.done').show();
    $(this).parents('.list-group-item').find('.mb-0.pending').hide();
})
```

```css
.mb-0.done{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
</div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
  </div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
  </div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
</div> <!-- /.form-check -->
    <div class="ml-auto status">
      <p class="mb-0 done">done</p>
      <p class="mb-0 pending">pending</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```